# Online application form in SharePoint Office 365

Tags: workflow, office-365

We are using Office365 and would like to replace our 
existing paper applications with a SharePoint form so we can then start a new hire workflow and avoid the mistakes of keying this ourselves.

Can we post this form to our public website in a way that non employees can submit it, if so how?

Can we store their SS#s on the field and are there any particular ways it needs secured?

Any examples of this on the web or recommendations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can create a workflow and allow user to submit it. There is no more public website offering in the Office 365.

You can take the advantage of security and compliance.

[Office 365 security and compliance](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn532171.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Check this blog for the example. https://www.dmcinfo.com/latest-thinking/blog/id/8569/onboarding-employees-using-sharepoint-workflow

Comment: If there is no more public website in office 365 does that mean they would only be able to fill out and view the form if they logged in to office 365?

Comment: that's what I believe.